# Why aren't F# records allowed to have AllowNullLiteralAttribute?

Tags: f#, attributes, nullable, record

Is there a compiler implementation reason why records can't have the AllowNullLiteralAttribute attribute or is this a chosen constraint?

I do see this constraint force cleaner code sometimes but not always.

```
[<AllowNullLiteralAttribute>]
type IBTreeNode = {
    mutable left : IBTreeNode; mutable right : IBTreeNode; mutable value : int}
with
    member this.Insert x =
        if x < this.value then
            if this.left = null then
                this.left <- {left = null; right = null; value = x}
            else
                this.left.Insert x
        else
            if this.right = null then
                this.right <- {left = null; right = null; value = x}
            else
                this.right.Insert x

// Would be a lot of boilerplate if I wanted these public
[<AllowNullLiteralAttribute>]
type CBTreeNode(value) = 
    let mutable left = null
    let mutable right = null
    let mutable value = value
with
    member this.Insert x =
        if x < value then
            if left = null then
                left <- CBTreeNode(x)
            else
                left.Insert x
        else
            if right = null then
                right <- CBTreeNode(x)
            else
                right.Insert x
```

Added an immutable version for the frown on mutability crowd.  It's about 30% faster in this case.

```
type OBTree =
    | Node of OBTree * OBTree * int
    | Null
with
    member this.Insert x =
        match this with
        | Node(left, right, value) when x <= value -> Node(left.Insert x, right, value)
        | Node(left, right, value) -> Node(left, right.Insert x, value)
        | Null -> Node(Null, Null, x)
```

Comment: As an aside, is there any particular reason why you need a mutable tree? I personally the immutable ones to be a lot more succinct, easier to work with, and more idiomatic in functional languages.

Comment: None mutable trees can get very complex to implement.  The above is a simple case but something like a none overlapping range tree gets messy when you try to implement insert and delete.  How do you handle the case of deleting cascading nodes or inserting a node that merges into multiple other nodes.  This kind of tree structure is inherently mutable.

Comment: "How do you handle the case of deleting cascading nodes or inserting a node that merges into multiple other nodes." -- just for funsies (and maybe for rep whoring too!), you ask another question on how to convert your mutable tree into an immutable one.

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes and I'll post it.

Answer (score 3):

I can only hazard a guess, but the language seems to take the position that the use of `null` is something to be avoided (you can always use an `option` type if you need that functionality), and so the use of `null` is really something that ought to be limited to interop with other .NET languages.  Therefore, F# specific types don't allow the use of `null`.

Comment: The constraint is definitely not at the CLR level : `AllowNullLiteral` applies to classes, and record types are (sealed) classes.  I expect that it may derive from OCAML (for the reasons stated above).

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, records are translated to standard .NET-classes like other constructs, so I don't see a technical reason.

I guess the decision is rather philosophical - `Null` values are uninitialized, undefined values, something that gets replaced within stateful computations. These are to be avoided in functional context like F#.

So I think that record types, as a "functional construct" (not standard .NET-compatible) aren't meant to carry such unfunctional data but the user is required to code it manually (`option types  etc.).

This also allows you to reason about your code and e.g. check a pattern matching for all possible values without the potential danger of having to deal with `null` values.

As to your code: Do you really require it to be that imperative? What about

```
data Tree = 
    | Node of int * Tree * Tree
    | Nil
```

Comment: Btw, Tony Hoare held a presentation about the null ref this summer: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare

Comment: The above is just a contrived example. My main concern is interop. Almost every major project I have ever worked on had a good amount of interop.