# Deserializing twitter stream json string F#, how to define 'null' as a proper value?

Tags: json, api, f#, twitter

I leave the below in case anybody wants the record types, but my question can be asked as following. 
Suppose one needs to write to a file  a record type that can be null, what is the best way to achieve that, considering the below yields: "The type 'Basic' does not have 'null' as a proper value":

```
type Basic = {Toto:string}

let basicToString b = function
    |null -> "null"
    |record->record.Toto
```

Thanks a lot

---

I have the following code to deserialize tweets from twitter  stream:

```
open System.Runtime.Serialization
open System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
open System
open System.Text
open System.IO  


  let  makeString numFields = 
    if numFields>1 then 
                seq[for i in 1..(numFields-1)->","]
                |> Seq.fold(fun elem res-> elem+res) ""
    else
        ""



[<DataContract>]
type boundingbox = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "type")>]
    t:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "coordinates")>]
    coordinates:float array array array
    }
    with 
        member this.ToCsv() = let temp =  string this
                              if temp ="" then 
                                  makeString 2
                              else
                                  this.t+","+"coordinates"




[<DataContract>]
type attributes = {
 [<field: DataMember(Name = "street_adress")>]
 street_adress:string
 }
    with 
        member this.ToCsv() = let temp =  string this
                              if temp ="" then 
                                  makeString 1
                              else
                                  this.street_adress



[<DataContract>]
type place = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "country")>]
    country:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "url")>]
    url:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "attributes")>]
    attributes:attributes 
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "country_code")>]
    country_code:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "full_name")>]
    full_name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
    name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
    id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "bounding_box")>]
    bounding_box:boundingbox
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "pldace_type")>]
    place_type:string
    }
    with 
        member this.toCsv() = let temp =  string this
                              if temp ="" then 
                                  makeString 10
                              else
                                  this.country+","+this.url+","+this.attributes.ToCsv()+","+this.country_code+","+this.full_name+","+this.name+","+this.bounding_box.ToCsv()+","+this.place_type



[<DataContract>]
type geo = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "type")>]
    t:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "coordinates")>]
    coordinates:float array
    }

[<DataContract>]
type url = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "url")>]
    url:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "indices")>]
    indices:int array
    }

[<DataContract>]
type hashtag = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "text")>]
    text:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "indices")>]
    indices:int array
    }


[<DataContract>]
type user_mention = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "indices")>]
    indices:int array
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "screen_name")>]
    screen_name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
    name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
    id:string
    }

[<DataContract>]
type entities = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "urls")>]
    urls:url array
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "hashtags")>]
    hashtags:hashtag array
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "user_mentions")>]
    user_mentions:user_mention array
    }

[<DataContract>]
type user = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "time_zone")>]
     time_zone:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_sidebar_border_color")>]
     profile_sidebar_border_color:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "screen_name")>]
    screen_name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "notifications")>]
     notifications:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "listed_count")>]
     listed_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_background_image_url")>]
     profile_background_image_url:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "location")>]
    location:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "statuses_count")>]
     statuses_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_background_color")>]
    profile_background_color:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "description")>]
     description:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "show_all_inline_media")>]
     show_all_inline_media:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_background_tile")>]
     profile_background_tile:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "contributors_enabled")>]
     contributors_enabled:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "geo_enabled")>]
     geo_enabled:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "created_at")>]
     created_at:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_text_color")>]
     profile_text_color:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "followers_count")>]
    followers_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_use_background_image")>]
    profile_use_background_image:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "url")>]
     url:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "friends_count")>]
     friends_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_link_color")>]
    profile_link_color:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "protected")>]
     Protected:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "lang")>]
     lang:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "verified")>]
     verified:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "name")>]
     name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "follow_request_sent")>]
     follow_request_sent:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "following")>]
     following:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "favourites_count")>]
     favourites_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_sidebar_fill_color")>]
     profile_sidebar_fill_color:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "profile_image_url")>]
    profile_image_url:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
    id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "utc_offset")>]
     utc_offset:string
}




[<DataContract>]
type tweet = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "place")>]
     place:place
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "geo")>]
     geo:geo
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "text")>]
    text:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "coordinates")>]
    coordinates:geo
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "retweet_count")>]
     retweet_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "favorited")>]
     favorited:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "source")>]
    source:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "contributors")>]
     contributors:int array
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "created_at")>]
    created_at:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_status_id")>]
    in_reply_to_status_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_screen_name")>]
    in_reply_to_screen_name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "user")>]
     user:user
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "retweeted")>]
    retweeted:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_user_id")>]
    in_reply_to_user_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "truncated")>]
     truncated:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
    tweet_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "entities")>]
    entities:entities
    }



[<DataContract>]
type fullTweet = {
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "place")>]
     place:place
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "geo")>]
     geo:geo
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "text")>]
    text:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "coordinates")>]
    coordinates:geo
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "retweet_count")>]
     retweet_count:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "favorited")>]
     favorited:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "source")>]
    source:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "contributors")>]
     contributors:int array
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "created_at")>]
    created_at:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_status_id")>]
    in_reply_to_status_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name="retweeted_status")>]
    retweeted_status:tweet
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_screen_name")>]
    in_reply_to_screen_name:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "user")>]
     user:user
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "retweeted")>]
    retweeted:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_user_id")>]
    in_reply_to_user_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "truncated")>]
     truncated:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "id")>]
    tweet_id:string
    [<field: DataMember(Name = "entities")>]
    entities:entities
    }



let decodeFullTweet (s:string)  = 
    let json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<fullTweet>)
    let byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
    let stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)
    json.ReadObject(stream) :?>fullTweet

let decodeUser (s:string)  = 
    let json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<user>)
    let byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)
    let stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)
    json.ReadObject(stream) :?>user
```

The next step I need to get done is to write each fullTweet record to a csv file, the issue is that sometimes some of the fields of the record type are null. For example when decoding the json string (the below is just a small part of the string ):

rel=\\"nofollow\\">TweetDeck\",\"favorited\":false,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[{\"text\":\"frac1\",\"indices\":[117,123]}],\"user_mentions\":[],\"urls\":[]},\"place\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"geo\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"

The fields "place" and "in_reply_to_user_id" will be null.

How can I handle this so that when a field is null (for example places), the csv line reads "null" ( for each field of the record type place) ? Or if you have a better way to handle this ?

Thanks a lot !!!

(Hope some will enjoy all the record types :) )

Comment: Do you already have some code or an idea how to generate the CSV file?  Otherwise, the question is difficult to answer. How to deal with the nulls depends on how the CSV file is created.

Comment: @wmeyer Thanks for looking at this. My question isn't very clear, sorry. I have edited my post with a solution that "works" but it seems slightly ugly.

Comment: Don't have an answer to your question, but find your use of folding in the makeString function very ingenious. However, if you wanted to leave that to the F# library, you could use 'let makeString numFields = String.init numFields (fun _ -> ",")' instead.

Comment: @Alexander Rautenberg Thanks for the tip it is a much nicer solution to use String.init

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you just need a function which will take a string and return the string if it is not null and return "null" if it is null:

```
let fieldToString = function
    | null -> "null"
    | field -> field
```

Comment: Swenson  Thanks for your help, for printing the field of a record this will work ( if the overall record is not null). The real issue is if you try to do it on the full record. I have edited my original question.

Comment: You might consider `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353608.aspx

Comment: @Brian Thanks. Do you know if there is anyway to use an option type when deserializing. In the fullTweet type, each field can exist or not (None/Some), and then each subfield can exist or not (None/Some), etc.. so an option type would seem very natural

Comment: F# records types don't allow nulls even with the AllowNullLiteral attribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856345